# Why don't I need to load shaders when using GLFW?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glfw

According to a book I'm reading, vertex and fragment shaders are *required* for the newest versions of OpenGL, and if they're not provided, rendering will not happen properly.

I'm using the GLFW library (3.0.4), and in the spinning triangle Hello World type example, there is no code to load the GPU with these shaders. I cannot find anything that says whether GLFW provides default shaders or not...

Below is the example code I'm referring to. There are calls to `glColor3f()`, which might be involved.

Also, I notice that the [OpenGL.org documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/) doesn't seem to list `glColor*()` at all! Why is this?

```
#include "GLFW\glfw3.h"

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float)height;

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef((float)glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
        glEnd();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: call `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);` before `glfwCreateWindow` if you want to disallow old OpenGL functionality. Also, literally all the OpenGL functions you called execept for `glViewport` and `glClear` aren't available in modern core OpenGl

Comment: Yes, I've figured that out. I'm just starting to learn about OpenGL, and it turns out there is a LOT of old stuff laying around the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glBegin` and `glEnd` indicate you use immediate mode aka the fixed function pipeline which predates shaders. That pipeline is also outdated and removed from 4.0+ core profiles.

Comment: Actually they've already been removed from core profiles since 3.2+